# Why does the basic AUTH box pop up twice in Chrome but not Firefox with spnego SSO

Tags: java, single-sign-on, spnego

I have a pretty vanilla spnego SSO setup which is authenticating against an Active Directory server.  The IE SSO contains the NEGOTIATE header cookie which is authenticating correctly without any prompting the user.  Firefox and Chrome do not contain the SSO cookie, and hence fail back to the basic authentication.  They do receive the username and password correctly and log in properly.

However, my minor annoyance is that it is prompting once in Firefox, but in Chrome it is prompting for the password twice.

Any ideas on why it could be prompting twice?

Setup below for completeness:

```
<filter>

    <filter-name>SpnegoHttpFilter</filter-name>

    <filter-class>net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoHttpFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.allow.basic</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.allow.localhost</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.allow.unsecure.basic</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.login.client.module</param-name>
        <param-value>spnego-client</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.krb5.conf</param-name>
        <param-value>xxxxxxxxxxxxx/krb5.conf</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.login.conf</param-name>
        <param-value>xxxxxxxxxxxx/login.conf</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.preauth.username</param-name>
        <param-value>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.preauth.password</param-name>
        <param-value>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.login.server.module</param-name>
        <param-value>spnego-server</param-value>
    </init-param>



    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.prompt.ntlm</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.allow.delegation</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>


</filter>
```

Comment: Just found the following:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341553/spnego-with-java-prompting-password-many-times  - it appears that perhaps Chrome is using the same methodology as IE - trying negotiate then basic...  I'll take a look at debugging it further as time allows

Comment: btw: Firefox has another, annoying issue related to password prompts https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=348997 fixed officially but I knew many users still complaining about (still in 36.0.1)

Answer (score 3):

This isn't an explanation why it pops up twice but it is a way to debug it in chrome.

Browse to **chrome:net-internals#events** and you can see the 401 auth negotiation. The 401 requests and responses do not appear in the network tab of the chrome dev tools, so this is the only clue you can get.

**Edit update** - it seems that Chrome does not always send the `Authorization` headers for `digest`. Either because of pipelining, an auth cache bug, or heuristics for which urls "inherit" the authorization.

From https://groups.google.com/d/msg/chromium-discuss/9ASzOBdBrTQ/wUWFlwFYwaMJ

> Since chromium will not pre-emptively send the authorization for
>   inferred protection space, it will keep entering that loop.
>
> [...]
>
> Support for Digest is likely, but a little sketchier, since the digest
>   auth model is broken under pipelining (next nonce is controlled by
>   previous server responses (Authorization-Info).

Because htdigest was causing two login dialogs every page load I switched to basic auth as my site was already using `HTTPS` for security. Basic and Digest do not define a scheme for which urls the `Authorization` token needs to be sent and for how long to cache the password or token. So it's slower and less secure than cookies. I'll try to avoid this scheme in the future.

Comment: **chrome:net-internals#events** no longer exists
Use: **chrome://net-export/** now instead.